# OSPF: inconsistent mask for area range?

Tags: cisco, ospf

In area 0 I have two loopbacks: 172.16.2.2 and 172.16.2.3 (both /24's).

I'm trying to configure a summary to roll the two up.  Given the rest of the topology, I'm using `area X range` command.

This is my input and the console's output.  What am I missing?

```
ZEUS(config-router)#area 0 range 172.16.2.0 255.255.252.0
% OSPF: Inconsistent address/mask 172.16.2.0/22 for area range
```

Wouldn't this summarize from 172.16.2.2 up to 172.16.3.255?

Comment: It might be useful to post relevant bits of the configurations as well as the platform/software version(s).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All loopbacks in OSPF are advertised with a 255.255.255.255 mask by default (see "LOOPBACK" network type), regardless of what you've configured the netmask as on the interface. If you want to announce your loopbacks with anything that's not a /32 you need to configure them as point-to-point (`ip ospf network point-to-point` under the Loopback interface configuration).

EDIT: Since you've stated you've already done this, my next observation is that you've given the wrong network address for the `area range` command. If you want to announce the summary you'd need to announce it with the network address, ie `area 0 range 172.16.0.0 255.255.252.0`

Also be aware that any traffic to 172.16.0.0/24 or 172.16.1.0/24 will be blackholed.

EDIT #2: @Christian's answer is also correct if you wanted to summarize **just** those two /24's into a /23: `area 0 range 172.16.2.0 255.255.254.0`

Comment: I've already done that, lets stay on topic, I'm asking why do I get the inconsistent address/mask feedback, when I know for a fact that the range of 172.16.2.0 255.255.252.0 includes both loopbacks?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: I figured it out: wrong subnetting!  Gragh, need to practice more.  It's inconsistent because .2 is half way through a block of 4 /24's, I moved it up to 172.16.4.0 255.255.252.0 to test this and it worked.  Doing 172.16.2.0 255.255.254.0 also worked to summarize the two loopbacks I had.  Thanks for all of your help, and enduring my ignorance!

Comment: A,L you wanted 2.0 thru 3.255. If you still want this range specifically simply change it to /23. See my answer

Comment: He already noted that in his comment above yours...

Comment: Wow you're totally right. Sorry, I was on mobile when I posted that; couldn't see well.

Comment: Either solution (`area 0 range 172.16.0.0 255.255.252.0` or `area 0 range 172.16.2.0 255.255.253.0`) would have worked, just with the former you'd run into issues with blackholing if you didn't have routes to cover the first two /24's within the /22 block.

Answer (score 3):

172.16.2.0 255.255.252.0 = 172.16.0.0-172.16.3.255

If you want .2.0 thru .3.255 specifically you'll need

172.16.2.0 255.255.254.0 = 172.16.2.0-172.16.3.255